# Moq & EF6 - Mocking EF6 Remove method not removing an object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-6, moq, xunit

I am trying to mock my EF6 `DbContext` and it all works for `Add`, `Update`, `Find` methods.  But it's not working for `Remove` method for unknown reason.

In theory, after removing, the `Students` collection should have only 1 return left.  But it keeps returning the Count - 2.

I put 3 Moq`.Verify` checks to ensure that all methods are called and they are executed indeed.  But it's not actually removing the item from the Students Collection.

If I commented `Assert.Equal` line which check the counts, the whole test passed.

**Delete XUnit Method**

```
[Fact]
public void Delete()
{            
    Mock<DbContexts.MVCWebAppDbContext> dbContext = new Mock<DbContexts.MVCWebAppDbContext>();
    IStudentsService studentService = new StudentsService(dbContext.Object);

    var students = new List<Student>()
    {
        new Student() { StudentID = 1, RefNo = "12456343", FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith", DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10), DateCreated = DateTime.Now },
        new Student() { StudentID = 2, RefNo = "87984564", FirstName = "Pete", LastName = "Luck", DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-20), DateCreated = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) }
    };

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Student>>();
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Student>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(students.AsQueryable().Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Student>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(students.AsQueryable().Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Student>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(students.AsQueryable().ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Student>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(students.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator());

    mockSet.Setup(m => m.Remove(It.IsAny<Student>())).Callback<Student>((entity) => students.Remove(entity));

    dbContext.Setup(c => c.Students).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    int idToDelete = 1;

    dbContext.Setup(s => s.Students.Find(idToDelete)).Returns(students.Single(s => s.StudentID == idToDelete));

    // call delete method now
    studentService.Delete(idToDelete);

    // 1 object deleted, it should return 1
    Assert.Equal(1, students.Count());  // <----- Error here

    dbContext.Verify(s => s.Students.Find(idToDelete), Times.Once);
    dbContext.Verify(s => s.Students.Remove(It.IsAny<Student>()), Times.Once);
    dbContext.Verify(s => s.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);
}
```

**StudentService.cs Delete method**

```
MVCWebAppDbContext _context;

public StudentsService(MVCWebAppDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public int Delete(int id)
{
    var objToDelete = _context.Students.Find(id);

    if (objToDelete != null)
    {
        _context.Students.Remove(objToDelete);
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Could you guys please help me with this Remove method mocking?

Comment: And what value Delete returns?

Comment: I have debugged it and it returns '1'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

replace

```
mockSet
    .Setup(m => m.Remove(It.IsAny<Student>()))
    .Callback<Student>((entity) => students.Remove(entity));
```

with

```
dbContext
    .Setup(m => m.Students.Remove(It.IsAny<Student>()))
    .Callback<Student>((entity) => students.Remove(entity));
```

Most of the setup was done using the `DbContext.Students` which overrides the setup on `DbSet.Remove`

In fact you can actually remove all the `DbSet` mocking and test would still pass

```
[Fact]
public void Delete() {
    var dbContext = new Mock<DbContexts.MVCWebAppDbContext>();
    IStudentsService studentService = new StudentsService(dbContext.Object);

    var students = new List<Student>()
    {
        new Student() { StudentID = 1, RefNo = "12456343", FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith", DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10), DateCreated = DateTime.Now },
        new Student() { StudentID = 2, RefNo = "87984564", FirstName = "Pete", LastName = "Luck", DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-20), DateCreated = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) }
    };

    dbContext
        .Setup(m => m.Students.Remove(It.IsAny<Student>()))
        .Callback<Student>((entity) => students.Remove(entity));

    int idToDelete = 1;

    dbContext
        .Setup(s => s.Students.Find(idToDelete))
        .Returns(students.Single(s => s.StudentID == idToDelete));

    // call delete method now
    studentService.Delete(idToDelete);

    // 1 object deleted, it should return 1
    Assert.AreEqual(1, students.Count());

    dbContext.Verify(s => s.Students.Find(idToDelete), Times.Once);
    dbContext.Verify(s => s.Students.Remove(It.IsAny<Student>()), Times.Once);
    dbContext.Verify(s => s.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);
}
```